# Django foreign key constraint with Model that lives in different database

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm, django-oauth

I'm trying to use the `oauth2_provider` library which provides a model for [AccessToken](https://github.com/jazzband/django-oauth-toolkit/blob/master/oauth2_provider/models.py#L243), which foreign keys into a User model. My User model will actually live in a different database from the OAuth2 token models. I can use a router to direct which DB to use for a particular model, but am I correct in concluding that Django would not support a foreign key to a model in a different DB?

If I still wanted to extend from the `AbstractAccessToken` with my User in a different DB, is there any way that Django allows me to populate the `user_id` foreign key column at all? Or would I simply need to leave it `null` and define and have my custom AccessToken class define its own unconstrained `external_user_id` column?

Comment: do you know database that support a foreign key to a table in a different DB?

Comment: Right, I'm not expecting a foreign key constraint to work, but the model comes with an expectation of a foreign key. I guess the question boils down to - is setting the FK to null and defining a new unconstrained id field the recommended way to re-use the model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django doesn't support any `ForeignKey` operations that span multiple databases. So, as you suggested, I think the best you can do is to provide your own `IntegerField` for the user and use it manually. Unfortunately that may require a lot of fiddling with that third-party library if it has a lot of internal code that's expecting to pull the user from the database.